# CSP issue when loading img pixel on Shopify check out page

Tags: image, e-commerce, shopify, checkout

We're creating a public [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) app which requires the user to embed the tracking code in their thank you page. We receive the following error in Chrome when the Thankyou page loads.

```
Refused to load the image, the message is a as follows because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https: blob: data:".
```

How can we fix this CSP (Content Security Policy) issue?

Comment: This is not my domain of expertise, but I think you may have to provide more details in your question in order to get an accurate answer.

Comment: @WhiteVking thanks for your kind answer. I'll elaborate a bit:
We are trying to implement img pixel at Shpofiy check-out page in order to track conversion. 

It looks as the server side prevents scripts and images to be opened from this page. 

The error the system shows us is: Refused to load the image '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https: blob: data:".

Hope that this is enough info to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Did you try to call this image from an SSL?

Comment: @alexandresaiz , I didn't really get how by adding HTML code (client side) i can be responsible of changes in SSL (Server side).

Comment: @EyalTorjman pleas post the code you're injecting in the thank you page which gives you this error. Also the source code of the rendered html page of thank you page with error would help.

Comment: @alexandresaiz , i implemented the following code: 
'<div class="thank-you__additional-content">
      
<img src="http://rdr.merchico.com/v/convert?tkn=55f92496afae607e548b4618&prd=2521332931%3B&prc=200.00##200.00%3B&curr=GBPorder=1003" height="1" width="1" />
    </div>
</div>'

Thank in advance,
Eyal

Comment: @EyalTorjman please put everything within your question

Comment: @EyalTorjman Hi mate, I ran into the same issue. Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67277614/content-security-violation-in-shopify/72226377#72226377

Answer (score 4):

[Content Security Policy](https://scotthelme.co.uk/content-security-policy-an-introduction/) is a HTTP response header that controls where the browser is allowed to load certain types of content from. The error message from Chrome provides the policy directive:

```
img-src 'self' https: blob: data:
```

The [img-src](https://scotthelme.co.uk/csp-cheat-sheet/#img-src) directive tells the browser where it is permitted to load image assets (`<img>`) from. The allowed sources for images according to this policy are `'self'`, which is your own domain, `https:` which permits any host using https and then `'blob'` and `'data'` which permit either of those URIs to be used.

At present you're trying to load your image from http://rdr.merchico.com, shown in your comment above. This does not match any of the allowed sources in your CSP. That domain seems to be served over https so if you change the `src` attribute of the image to https://rdr.merchino.com then it will be permitted by the CSP as it matches the `https:` source.