# Content Security Violation in Shopify

Tags: ajax, shopify, content-security-policy

I am using Shopify and I'm making an ajax get request to a different server. I have just implemented it so I'm testing it on the console. The request is getting through and I'm getting the response I want but I am also getting the following message:

> [Report Only] Refused to connect to 'https://myurl.com/ApiClientes/ciudades' because it violates the >following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' *.shopifycloud.com *.shopifysvc.com >*.amazon.com *.paypal.com *.facebook.com sessions.bugsnag.com analytics.tiktok.com bat.bing.com >www.google-analytics.com ct.pinterest.com stats.g.doubleclick.net".

I would like to get rid of it. Don't know what it is or what it means. I could really use some help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you need to provide more information, like app you creating and hosting server on that APP is hosted.

Comment: Just add `myurl.com` to the `connect-src` directive. And from where are the `>` chars in the policy? They shouldn't be there.

Comment: I think this is not going to affect anything in your code, it's just a [Report Only]. So it's only giving a report to you like the CSP is violated.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this issue, don't make direct request to third-party server instead create one url at 'https://yourdomain.com/anypath/handlereqeust?r={requestURL}' to handle all the requests from Shopify store

Then make request to Shopify app as mentioned in this link: https://shopify.dev/apps/online-store/app-proxies